# NullReferenceException for TimePicker Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, nullreferenceexception, timepicker

I am using timepicker  in my application but whenever I give it a default value then NullReferenceException appears in valuechange function.My code is

```
 private void timePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        var time = (DateTime)timePicker1.Value;

        // time.ToShortTimeString()
        MessageBox.Show(time.ToString("H:mm"));

        writeTimeFile(time);
        ResetAlarm();
        setTheAlarm();


    }
```

Actually whenever I start my application,the timepicker shows current time but I want it to show some specific value say 00:00 or 12:00.

Comment: How are you setting the default value?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting the value of your time picker object correctly. This worked for me. Also verify something else isn't throwing the `NullReferenceException`.

```
    public TimePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // setting default value for TimePicker here
        EventTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Parse("12:00 AM");
    }

    private void TimePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var time = (DateTime) EventTimePicker.Value;
        MessageBox.Show(time.ToShortTimeString());
    }
```